# How to organize the data of an object containing an array of objects with same key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, flatmap

Hi guys so I am trying to set up a little survey app, I am now building my survey result page, which will display the results of a given survey.
The data that I am fetching is an array  of object with `answers` arrays inside them.

```
{ totalAnswers: [ 
  { answers: [answer0, answer1, answer2, answer3] }, 
  { answers: [Array] }, 
... ] }
```

I am wondering how to display the data since all the objects keys are all the same, but the arrays also all have the same length... Any leads are welcomed :)

---

Edit:
I figured that I wasn't clear enough in what I am trying to achieve, and I apologize for that.

So basically in this survey web app that I am building. I want to enable the survey creator to , optimally, be
able to view the answer data of each question seperately. Or at least be able to display those answers on the DOM.
To be able to do so I should somehow find a way to destructure this big `totalAnswers` array containing objects having each an `answers` array.

The `answers.length` can vary depending on the number of the questions that the survey has. And the number of objects with an answer array may also vary depending on the number of survey answers.

But whenever I try to do `console.log(totalAnswers.length)` it is returning `undefined` so does it mean that it might be an object after all ? I thought that since there were brackets after `totalAnswer` it meant that it was an array.

Comment: seems readable to me. what is the expected output?

Comment: I would like to be able to differentiate these different objects. Right now I am unable to destructure any bits of this response

Comment: The OP is encouraged and supposed to provide a boiled down example code of some input data structure (does neither need to be the full `totalAnswers` array length nor each `answer` items array length) and the expected result (from the boiled down input example) both with real key names or a key pattern which the OP considers working for an example case.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Alright thank you for the insights, I appreciate that, I tried to make the context a bit better, any other further suggestions are welcomed

Comment: @GiorgioDG ... Regarding the so far provided approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one string of comma-separated answers per answer index:

```js
console.log(totalAnswers[0].answers.map((_,i)=>totalAnswers.map(a=>a.answers[i]).join()));
```

Comment: this line  will return  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` but thanks fren

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the OP is looking for a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) based approach/solution?

```js
const answerBlob = {
  totalAnswers: [{
    answers: [{ answerItem1: {} }, { answerItem2: {} }, { answerItem3: {} }, { answerItem3: {} }],
  }, {
    answers: [{ answerItem1: {} }, { answerItem2: {} }, { answerItem3: {} }],
  }, {
    answers: [{ answerItem1: {} }, { answerItem2: {} }],
  }],
};
const flatAnswerList = answerBlob
  .totalAnswers
  .flatMap(({ answers }) => answers);

console.log({
  answerBlob,
  flatAnswerList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```